# SQLException when accessing H2 metamodel through JOOQ-meta

Tags: jdbc, h2, jooq

I am trying to obtain a list of all tables in my H2 in-memory DB using JOOQ's `DSLContext.meta()`:

```
DSL_CONTEXT_PROVIDER.db().meta().getTables();
```

results in:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: Error while accessing DatabaseMetaData
        at MyTest.deleteEntities(MyTest.java:222)
        at MyTest.cleanupDatabase(MyTest.java:201)
        at MyTest.afterTestCase(MyTest.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        [... omitted for brevity ...]
    Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: Error while accessing DatabaseMetaData
        at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getCatalogs(MetaImpl.java:160)
        at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getSchemas(MetaImpl.java:168)
        at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getTables(MetaImpl.java:179)
        at MyTest.deleteEntities(MyTest.java:210)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-174]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:138)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1410)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1388)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseMetaData.checkClosed(JdbcDatabaseMetaData.java:2963)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseMetaData.getCatalogs(JdbcDatabaseMetaData.java:756)
        at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getCatalogs(MetaImpl.java:143)
        ... 32 more
```

`DSL_CONTEXT_PROVIDER.db()` looks like this:

```
JdbcDataSource h2ds = new JdbcDataSource();
h2ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:testDB;create=true");
h2ds.setUser("");
h2ds.setPassword("");
return DSL.using(new DefaultConfiguration().set(new DataSourceConnectionProvider(h2ds)));
```

Ordinary queries work fine with the above configuration, but not the `meta().getTables()`. If I replace `DataSourceConnectionProvider` with an anonymous implementation that doesn't close the connection, no exception is thrown anymore.

It seems H2 does not approve of calling methods like `getCatalogs()` on the object returned by `connection.getMetaData()` after the underlying connection has been closed. Is this this a bug in `jooq-meta` (I use 3.7.0) or is my configuration flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ 3.7.0 / 3.7.1 and earlier are caching the `DatabaseMetaData` in `org.jooq.Meta`. This is a bug ([4762](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4762)) and will be fixed soon.

The reason why you're running into this issue is because you're using the `DataSourceConnectionProvider`, which isn't really intended to work with standalone connections, or "simple" `DataSources`. It closes the connection after every query (which normally translates to returning it to the pool). After closing the connection, the cached `DatabaseMetaData` reference is stale.

You've already documented the workaround: Don't use a "simple" `DataSource` with jOOQ's `DSLContext.meta()` API.